# Android: call main activity method from Async onPostExecute method

Tags: android, asynchronous

Trying to call `MainActivity` method on `onPostExecute()`, but not getting any success. I tried so many things, but I think I am doing something wrong. `processFinish()` method on `MainActivity` is not called from `onPostExecute()`.

```
//myClass.java
public class myClass extends Activity   {
    public AsyncResponse delegate=null;

    public myClass(Context context){
          this.mContext = context;
    }

    public interface AsyncResponse {
        void processFinish(String output);
    }
    public class GetNotification extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String>{
        public GetNotification() {
             super();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... mArgs){
              //code
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
          super.onPostExecute(result);
          delegate.processFinish(result); 
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
        }
    }
    public void getValue(int f){
        m_flag = f;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
            new GetNotification().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, f);
        }
        else{
            new GetNotification().execute(f);
        }
    }
}


//MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AsyncResponse{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //code
        }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(String output){
        getComActivity(output);
    }

    private void getData(String mURL){
        this.getUrl=new com.sample.myClass(this);
        getUrl.getValue(1);


    }
    public void getComActivity(String gStr){
        if (gStr != null && gStr.trim() != ""){
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), myActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you setting the delegate in  myClass . its null, right?

Comment: return String in doInBackground it will set valuie for onPostExecute(String result)

Comment: My question is out of your question :  Why are you extending Activity for `myClass`? where as  you can simple execute AsyncTask in separate class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialze `delegate`. Change the code in `myClass` constructor.

```
public myClass(Context context){
      delegate = (AsyncResponse) context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> public GetNotification() {
>                super();
>           }

```
//In your AsyncTask class
//use MainActivity or myClass instead of Activity
private Activity activity;
public GetNotification(Activity activity) {
   this.activity = activity;
}
private void callMethod()
{
   activity.some_method();
}
```

Comment: I am new for Android(java). Please elaborate in details it looks interesting

Answer (score 0):

```
public class myClass extends Activity   {

    public AsyncResponse delegate=null;
    Context mContext;


    public myClass(Context context){
          this.mContext = context;

    }

    public interface AsyncResponse {
        void processFinish(String output);
    }


 public class GetNotification extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String>{

     public GetNotification() {
             super();
        }


         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute(){
             //start dialog progress over here
         }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... mArgs){
              //code
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
          super.onPostExecute(result);
          delegate.processFinish(result);

        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void getValue(int f){
       int m_flag = f;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
            new GetNotification().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, f);
        }
        else{
            new GetNotification().execute(f);

            if( MainActivity.activity!=null)
              MainActivity.getComActivity("PassYourStringOverHere");      //here I am giving example how to call MainActivity method from other activity


       }
    }
```

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AsyncResponse{

    private myClass getUrl;
    public static Activity activity=null;
    public static Context context=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        activity=this;//use to initialize the activity...later you can call...and start intent using this activity object...
        context=this;//use for Intent...why I used this pattern because i made a static method so I have to do...or else it will show error...
        //code
        }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(String output){
        getComActivity(output);
    }

    private void getData(String mURL){
        this.getUrl=new com.sample.myClass(this);
        getUrl.getValue(1);


    }
    public static  void getComActivity(String gStr){
        if (gStr != null && gStr.trim() != ""){
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, myActivity.class);
            activity.startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    }
}
```